# How to return one value from ETS in Elixir?

Tags: erlang, elixir, ets

i have ETS table that have key values scheme like this:

```
users = :ets.tab2list(:users)
IO.inspect users # printing

[
{"3eadd68495d",
%UserType{
 name: "John",
 id: "3eadd68495d",
 status: "Free"
}},
{"234a34495d",
%UserType{
 name: "Steve",
 id: "234a34495d",
 status: "Free"
}},
{"9add68495d",
%UserType{
 name: "Mike",
 id: "9add68495d",
 status: "Busy"
}}
]
```

And I want to get one id of any element, that have status "Free".

I'm already tried to get value using loop

```
users = :ets.tab2list(:users)
for user <- users do
   userValue = user |> elem(1)
   if userValue.status === "Free" do
     userValue.id
   end
end
```

but it returns multiple id values (3eadd68495d234a34495d), not one

i need smth like "break" after `if userValue.status === "Free" do userValue.id` but i have no idea how to use this in Elixir.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ it makes zero sense to use triple-equal [`===/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#===/2) on anything but a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the single value, one should use [`Enum.reduce_while/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce_while/3).

```elixir
Enum.reduce_while(users, nil, fn
  {_, %UserType{status: "Free", id: id}}, _ -> {:halt, id}
  _, acc -> {:cont, acc}
end)
```

or as pointed out by @sabiwara in comments, use `Enum.find_value/2`.

---

I would not recommend this, but one might do [`try/catch`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#try/1) to “break” the `for` comprehension as shown below.

```elixir
try do
  for {_, %UserType{status: "Free", id: id}} <- users, do: throw(id)
catch
  id -> id
end
```

---

*Sidenote:* generally speaking, it is extremely inefficient and once you already have *ETS*, you’d better be using `:ets.select/2` as described in https://write.as/yuriploc/ets-dets-match-patterns-and-specifications

Somewhat alongside the following lines should do

```elixir
:ets.select(
  :users,
  [{{:_, %{status: :"$1", id: :"$2"}},
   [{:"==", :"$1", "Free"}],
   [:"$2"]}])
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Aleksei! Enum.reduce_while/3 works exactly how I want.
But I would like to know a little bit more about efficiency between using first solution (ets.tab2list and then getting first element using Enum.reduce) and using ets.select - if i understand right, in first solution we just copy all values from ets table to list and then searching for required value (this is O(n) but if value in first element - it will be constant O(1)). In another, ets.select - we searching for all values in entire table and it will be always O(n), even if value in first element.

Comment: Why would you think `:ets.tab2list/1` is instant? It’s already `O(n)` in the first place. Probably [`:ets.match/3`](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#match-3) would be a better fit to retrieve the first element only, but `:ets.select/2` is also good enough.

Comment: Since you don't need an accumulator, [`Enum.find_value/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#find_value/2) would probably be even better than `reduce_while` or a try/catch for this kind of case. But I agree `:ets.select` should be preferred here to avoid copying the whole list.

Comment: @sabiwara I tend to memorize the syntax of `Enum.reduce/3` and `Enum.reduce_while/3` instead of all these sugars like `Enum.frequencies/1` etc :) but sure `Enum.find_value/2` is a better fit here.